# Solr nested fields

Tags: solr

I'm using Solr 8.11 and I'm trying to use nested fields in my document, like follows.

```
{ 
  albums: [
    artists: [
      {
        name: "Missy Elliott",
        popularity: 75
      }
    ],
    name: "The Cookbook" 
  ]
}
```

However, when I try to retrieve any data (using Solr admin), it comes like this:

```
{ 
  albums.artists.name: ['Missy Elliott'],
  albums.artists.popularity: [75],
  albums.name: ['The Cookbook']
}
```

Comment: What is your question? And what are you using to retrieve the data? I don't recognize the format you've shown.

Comment: I want the nested field to be retrieve like the example above
Also, it's JSON

Comment: What code are you using to retrieve the data? Please edit the question to show us the code that you executed to get that data.

Comment: It's just what Solr admin returns

Comment: To use nested documents in Solr, your schema has to meet some requirements. See https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_0/indexing-nested-documents.html.  The sweet spot for Solr is search over massive amounts of lightly structured data, for which the effort involved in deploying and maintaining it is justified.  You could also consider different technologies (e.g., MongoDB) that might be an smoother fit for persisting and searching JSON-like data structures.